# Can I use Corona sdk for making non-game apps?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, coronasdk

Can I use Corona http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/ for making non-game apps? I mean non-game application with a lot of buttons, tables, charts, reports,selects and so on.

I need it to create-cross platform mobile application.

Comment: Are you allowed? YES. Is it a good idea? Maybe. There might be a better pre-existing tool which would make your development faster and more intuitive.

Comment: There's also Titanium for cross platform: http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/, it's like Corona, but "standard"-app centered. I don't have experience with it although. I personally prefer native, it has many advantages over cross-platform and is more interesting. The only but not negligible disadvantage is that it requires more experience/developers/time (although I'm not sure about time factor, sometimes you spend a lot of time on those cross-plattform things hacking solutions which are straight-forward on native).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are limitations in using Corona SDK for Enterprise Applications. Some of the are below:

- Most of the well known third party libs and frameworks cannot be used
  with Corona SDK.
- Some of the features offered by the underlying operating systems
  cannot be used.
- Features available on iOS are not available on Android.
- Third Party SDKs would be always behind from the new features
  introduced by the native mobile SDKs

Refer [this](http://www.cutemachine.com/product-creation/learn-how-to-develop-apps-for-ios-and-android-with-corona-sdk/)

So in short, you need to know the complete specifications of your app, and research if it is possible using Corona SDK and then start with your project

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe you could suggest me some other cross-platform frameworks for mobile business apps creation ?

Comment: It all depends on what all functionality you want in your app. Refer the [blog1](http://floatlearning.com/2011/07/which-cross-platform-framework-is-right-for-me/) and [blog2](http://mashable.com/2010/08/11/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/). One suggestion would be choosing SDK having Debugger and emulator support. That you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development)

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I need. After first look I think Appcelerator Titanium looks for me pretty promising.

Answer (score 2):

Yes .... You can do that... Its good platform for all kind of apps

Answer (score 1):

From the website you pointed at...

> Corona is renowned for game creation, but is an equally powerful tool
>   for other app types including business apps, utility apps, educational
>   apps, eBooks and more.

Answer (score 1):

Both Corona and Titanium are excellent choices for any kind of utility or "non-game" app. There are pros and cons to each, of course, which are largely matter of opinion.

That said, you can look at this page here: http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/case-studies/

- On the right you will see a bunch of apps done in Corona that are utilities/business/non-game apps.

Some are really very impressive, some very successful and may help you make up your mind.